# Uncaught Error: Class not found en PHP al llamar una clase desde otra, en el mismo fichero

Tags: poo, php7

Os pongo el caso específico: llamo a la clase `TextGenerator`, ella, a su vez, llama desde su constructor a la clase `ObjectJson` y la respuesta es:

> Uncaught Error: Class 'ObjectJson' not found.

Código:

```
$lista = new TextGenerator();
ConvertJson($lista->GetData());

class ObjectJson implements JsonSerializable{

    public function __construct(array $data){
       $this->Titulo = $data['Titulo'];
       $this->Criterio = $data['Criterio'];                 
    }

    public function jsonSerialize()
    {       
         return
        [
           'titulo'   => $this->getTitulo(),
           'criterio' => $this->getCriterio(),           
        ];
    }    
}

class TextGenerator{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $clase = new ObjectJson($struct);        //Aquí salta el error del servidor
        $Criterios[] = $clase;  

        $this->Data = $Criterios; 
    }

    public function GetData(){
    return $this->Data;
    }

 }
```

Lo extraño es que cuando pongo las clases en otro archivo y hago lo siguiente todo funciona perfectamente:

```
require("archivo2");
$lista = new TextGenerator();
ConvertJson($lista->GetData());
```

Este asunto me está volviendo loco porque no le veo sentido al error.

Answer (score 0):

A la luz del éxito al pedir ayuda he resuelto el problema. Gracias, entre todos me curtís. El problema era que primero se ha de declarar las clases para después poder instanciarlas. Es decir:

```
class TextGenerator{                    //Primero declaras la clase

   public function __construct()
   {
      $clase = new ObjectJson($struct);        
      $Criterios[] = $clase;  

      $this->Data = $Criterios; 
   }

   public function GetData(){
      return $this->Data;
   }
}
```

Y después:

```
$lista = new TextGenerator();       //Después la instancias
```

En este orden y no en otro.

Comment: que bueno que encontraste la solución, pero deberías leer un poco de inyección de dependencias super util para estos casos.

Comment: Gracias, lo haré.